# Displaying values from mysql db - fetch_object() error

Tags: php

I am submitting values from the form into mysql db. After, I am performing a select query to try to grab those previously inserted values and display their result. I am using a while loop to iterate and display just two values `academy_id` and academy `name`. When trying to display this values I get an error `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_object()` .  How can I fix this error and display the values wanted? [Example](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/test9.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


$db_insert  = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO academy (name, type, status, academy_id, street_address, zipcode, city, state, comments) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
$db_insert->bind_param('sssisssss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['type'], $_POST['status'], $_POST['acad_id'], $_POST['street'], $_POST['zipcode'], $_POST['city'], $_POST['state'], $_POST['acad_comm']);
$db_insert->execute();

$academy_id = $_POST['acad_id'];



 //Query to Read Values from database based on academy_id 
$db_select  = $db_con->prepare("
SELECT a.name AS 'Academy Name:', 
       a.academy_id AS 'Academy ID:',
       a.status AS 'STATUS:',
       a.type AS 'Type:',
       a.street_address AS 'Street:',
       a.city AS 'City:',
       a.state AS 'State:',
       a.zipcode AS 'Zip Code:',
       a.comments AS 'Comments:'
FROM academy a
WHERE a.academy_id = $academy_id
");
$db_select->bind_param("i", $academy_id);
$db_select->execute();

while ($row = $db_select->fetch_object()) {
    echo "<h2>Result:</h2><br>";
    echo "Academy ID: " . $academy_id. "<br>";  
    echo "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "<br>";        
} 
}

?>
<form action="test9.php" method="POST">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"></br> 
        Academy Status:
        <select>
          <option value="ACTIVE">ACTIVE</option>
          <option value="INACTIVE">INACTIVE</option>
        </select>
        Type:
        <select>
          <option value="Upper-Secondary">Upper-Secondary</option>
          <option value="Post-Secondary">POST SECONDARY</option>
        </select>

        Courses being offered?
        <select name="courses_offered">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
        <div id="course_catalog"></div>
        Academy ID: <input type="text" id="acad_id" name="acad_id"></br>
        Address: <input type="text" id="street" name="street"></br>
        Zip Code: <input type="text" id="zip_input" name="zipcode"></br>
        City: <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value=""></br>
        State: <input type="text" id="state" name="state" value=""></br>
        Overall Notes/Comments:</br><textarea id="acad_comm" name="acad_comm" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></br>

    <input value="SAVE" name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message looks accurate to me: the [mysqli_stmt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) class does not have any `fetch_object()` method I can spot.

Please have a look at some of the [usage examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php#example-1628). You are not supposed to fetch results from the statement but from the [`mysqli_result` object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) returned by:

```
$db_insert->execute();
```

You're also doing no error checking at all. This should fail:

```
$db_select->bind_param("i", $academy_id);
```

... because there query doesn't contain any place-holder:

```
WHERE a.academy_id = $academy_id
```

.... should be:

```
WHERE a.academy_id = :academy_id
```

But you don't check any result value so you'll end up guessing.

Comment: How can I fix `$db_select->bind_param("i", $academy_id);`?

Comment: +1 Yes, Made the change but it is now showing error with `bind_param`

Answer (score 0):

you can try fetch or fetchAll and while and foreach both are ok

```
while ($row = $db_select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<h2>Result:</h2><br>";
    echo "Academy ID: " . $academy_id. "<br>";  
    echo "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "<br>";        
} 

foreach ($db_select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    echo "<h2>Result:</h2><br>";
    echo "Academy ID: " . $academy_id. "<br>";  
    echo "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "<br>";   
}
```

Comment: It's not like you can stick together functions from any database extension and make it work.